# Rails 4.1 model associations. Controller and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations, view, render

I try to learn rails by myself. I created simple app by using scaffold and resource generator. I created blog app which has user and article model. everything was fine until I want to show articles which user associated in user profile. I believe something wrong with controller. Also there is nothing wrong with articles/show.

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
end
```

article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

users controller:

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def show
    @article = @user.articles.find(params[:user_id])

  end
```

articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @article = @user.articles.new
    end
    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @article = @user.articles.new(params.require(:article).permit!)
        if @article.save
            redirect_to user_article_path(:user_id)
        else 
            render :new
        end 
    end
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @article = @user.articles.find(params[:user_id])

    end

end
```

users view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Username:</strong>
  <%= @user.username %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Password:</strong>
  <%= @user.password %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
<%= link_to 'new article', new_user_article_path(@user) %><br>

<%= @article.title %><br>
<%= @article.body %>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :users do
    resources :articles
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that user#show is the problem, in that method you should get all the articles of the respective user, so it should be

```
@articles = @user.articles
```

Also if you can't see the any articles then check in the rails console if the articles are in the database and if the field user_id is not nil

```
rails c
Article.all
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I alredy checked db. No nil in db. I also the managed the controller as you did. but it doesn't work. In model assciatons it kind of hard to configure. Im a bit confused.

Comment: the model is okay, in the rails console you check it, just select an user with user = User.first (or last) and then user.articles, if you get an empty array or the articles of the user it is okay.

Comment: also you can check the article model looking for the user, just use Article.first.user and you should get the corresponding user or nil.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. Looks like I didn't setup my view properly.Now it works finally.